# migration still runs code when it has been commented out

Tags: ruby, post, migration

I have code that has been commented out in a migration yet when I run the migration the code still attempts to run. 
It gives the following error:

```
error is PG::Error: ERROR:  column "rount_id" of relation "rounds" does not exist
```

The error above is the reason why it has been commented out.

```
def up
  remove_column :rounds, :rount_id
end
def down
  add_column :rounds, :rount_id, :integer
end
```

Comment: can you add the corresponding migration file.

Comment: #def up
      ##  remove_column :rounds, :rount_id
      #end
      #def down
      #  add_column :rounds, :rount_id, :integer
      #end

Comment: Are you sure you saved migration after you commented it out? Are you also sure this error is thrown by the migration above? Can't you edit your question?

Comment: @BroiSatse the migration has been saved. if it is not the migration what else could it be?

Comment: `#def up                                                                  ## remove_column :rounds, :rount_id                                 #end                                                              #def down                                                            # add_column :rounds, :rount_id, :integer                         #end`

Comment: @maggus - It might be different migration. :) Btw, you shouldn't comment out methods definition, just their body, i.e `def up` and `end` should not be commented out. ALso, can you click this small `edit` link under your question? I don't remember whether you need higher reputation for this.

Comment: sorry about the editing I still can't get the formatting right to display. I used `` on the start and end of the code and pushed the space bar til I got to the end of the textbox

Comment: @BroiSatse you were right I looked at the error more closely and it was a different migration

Comment: @maggus - you are not editing a question, you are posting comments. :) To edit question, there is a link `edit` just under your question (together with `share`, `close`, `delete` and `flag`).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are running it on development

Replace your migration file with the following code,

```
def change
  remove_column :rounds, :rount_id, :integer
end
```

And run

> rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV="development"

if you are going to comment it, do it like

```
def change
  #remove_column :rounds, :rount_id, :integer
end
```